# Json jQuery and php doesn't process value's correct

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have : Html + jQuery + ajax post and a PHP file to process the form values and returning a error(true or false) and a message with html markups.

My javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('#form'); // contact form
  var submit = $('#submit');  // submit button
  var alert = $('.alert'); // alert div for show alert message

  // form submit event
  form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

    $.ajax({
      url: 'contact.php', // form action url
      type: 'post', // form submit method get/post
      dataType: 'json', // request type html/json/xml
      data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data
      beforeSend: function() {
        alert.fadeOut();
        submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
      },
    success: function(result) {
        if(result.error){
            /* On error stuff */
            alert(result.html).fadeIn();
        }else{
            /* On success stuff */
            alert(result.html).fadeIn();
        }
    }
    });
  });
});
```

and at last my php:

```
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) ){
$result = array("error" => false, "html" => null);
$vars = array('name', 'email','telefoonnummer', 'message');
$verified = TRUE;
foreach($vars as $v) {
   if(!isset($_POST[$v]) || empty($_POST[$v])) {
      $verified = FALSE;
   }
}      

if(!$verified) {


$result["error"] = true;
$result["html"] = "<b>Error11</b>";
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit;
}    

$name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$tel= filter_var($_POST['telefoonnummer'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $to = '';
$sent = email($to, $email, $name, $tel, $message);
if ($sent) {
$result["error"] = false;
$result["html"] = "<b>Success</b>";
    echo json_encode($result);
} else {
$result["error"] = true;
$result["html"] = "<b>Error</b>";
    echo json_encode($result);
    }

  return;
}

/**
 * Email send with headers
 *
 * @return bool | void
 **/
function email($to, $name, $email, $tel, $message){
  $header = array();
  $header[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
  $header[] = "From: <".$name."> <".$email.">";

  /* Set message content type HTML*/
  $header[] = "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
  $header[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
  if( mail($to, $tel, $message, implode("\r\n", $header)) ) return true;
}
```

Ok.. now that's clear I know something goes wrong with the error returning, it does show up and then goes away again n my html so I don't know what exactly happens there..

I don't want "fixes" just so i can copy paste the code but an explanation of what happened and what goes wrong and how to solve it (at least then I learn a little)

Comment: Welcome! One tip it would be better to paste your code into the question rather than providing links

Comment: I tried and it messed up the marks so i used pastebin since it has better code recognition.

Comment: You can use both. The idea is that if your pastebin link gets broken the question will become useless for other users since they won't be able to see the code.

Comment: Ok thnx for the tip, I was gonna replace them with public links to my account since i came accros that in my mind already. thnx anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `alert` in two different ways... One time as an object, one time as a function. The latter is probably what causes the undesired effect. Look closely at the brackets after `alert`;

- `alert()` is a function
- `alert.` signafies it's an object

Comment: replacing the . Would be fine then ?

Comment: I think you need to replace `alert(result.html).fadeIn();` with `alert.html(result.html).fadeIn();`. I am not sure though whether you can use `alert` as a name for a variable... A more suitable name would be `notice` imho.

Comment: ahhh damn.. it needs double .html.. hmmm gonna try it and post the results. :)

Comment: Ok ok cool it works, every way i wanted it to. Can somebody please vote this up since i cant? 

Still got a little "style" question regarding my js.

the:  submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
now doesnt work not.. aldo it worked with a other type of AJAX datatype and other succes function.. strange.. can you explain this?

Comment: Ah and with the object i needed to target the alert. to the .HTML i get it.. thnx again :)

Comment: You should use `submit.val('Sending...');` since the text of an `input type="submit"` is changed by changing its value. It doesn't have any HTML content...

Comment: Ok strange. With some other JS code it worked fine. Now i try with.val but it doesn't change it. 

you can try the script @ http://www.buitenaangelegenheden.nl/ . @ the bottom of the page is my contact form

Comment: You are referring to your submit by id `submit` in the following code: `$('#submit');` On the supplied page, I can however not see `id="submit"` within the html of the submit-button... It should be `<input type="submit" class="button alt" value="Send Message" id="submit">`

Comment: Ok. Guess i'm today a little slow, i thought it would attach to type=submit

Comment: No... You can select all submit-buttons on the page with `$('input[type=submit]');`, but since you only need this one button, you need to set an id for it ;)

Comment: Thanks again dude! Still i find it strange it worked with submit.html without setting a id before, after i changed the script to deal with JSON in place of HTML it didn't but this fixed everything i wanted to know. Now i can use this for other type of applications i want to build :)

Comment: No problem... To bad you selected a different answer as the solution to your question though...

Comment: Oh wait i clicked it not because it was the answer, i can't do the + yet. Thnx for giving me the notice :)

Answer (score 1):

We cannot use jquery chaining method in alert function.

Comment: Thanks dude! this info adds to the above so i can understand better what the difference is. I Didn't know jquery is all about chaining ^^,